# Is it possible to use google cloud sdk installed in windows host from ubuntu guest?

Tags: python, virtualbox, google-cloud-sdk

back then i used to work in linux environment, but in my current work i got bound to using only windows. Everything worked fine eventually but then just recently i got to problem wherein i need to use `uwsgi` package which is incompatible with windows, so i my solution was to use virtualbox, install ubuntu there and then just run that single standalone module which needs `uwsgi` and the rest still with windows (each module communicates through HTTP, so they kind of like microservices). Now the thing is all of them depends in google cloud sdk which currently installed in my windows machine (host) so my plan is to move that installation to the shared folder between the guest and host to be able to be used by them, but wondering if it will work? as much as possible i dont like make the guest ubuntu to be bulky that much

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the folder of the Cloud SDK installed on the host machine with a guest OS on Virtualbox should be working as long as the required environmental variables (e.g $PATH) are appropriately configured on the guest OS.